# reference в mongodb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

Уже много времени потратил в попытках сделать референс между двумя документами в mongoDB.

Структура В БД следующая

Коллекция company:

```
{
    _id:6093dfd6e2ba3102ffdfa23a
    name:"Samsung"
}
```

Коллекция products:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("6093df74e2ba3102ffdfa238"),
    name: "Tel 1",
    company_id: [ObjectId("6093dfd6e2ba3102ffdfa23a")] // по документации тут у меня референс
}
```

При API запросе продукта получаю следующий объект:

```
{
    _id: "6093df74e2ba3102ffdfa238",
    name: "Tel 1",
    company_id: ["6093dfd6e2ba3102ffdfa23a"]
}
```

Хотя ожидал, что на выходе получу объект такого вида:

```
{
    _id: "6093df74e2ba3102ffdfa238",
    name: "Tel 1",
    company_id: [
        {
            _id:6093dfd6e2ba3102ffdfa23a
            name:"Samsung"
        }
    ]
}
```

Может кто-то встречался с такой проблемой, как правильно настроить референс?

Comment: Монго - это не реляционная база данных, она в общем случае не знает, на что именно ссылается этот ObjectId. Да даже и в реляционной базе данные из другой таблицы волшебным образом бы не вытащились без явного на это указания (JOIN). В монге для этого надо использовать aggregation framework и оператор [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-lookup).